# Name of the algorithm for choosing an element from a list based on its "width"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, collections, naming, weighted

I have the following algorithm, presented here in a simplified version in Rusty pseudocode:

```rust
fn foo<T>(elements: list<T>, weights: list<float>, offset: float) -> Option<T> {
    for i in 0..elements.length() {
        offset -= weights[i];
        if (offset <= 0) {
            return Some(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return None;
}
```

in other words, given `elements=["a", "b", "c"]` and `weights=[1, 3, 2]`, illustrated here as laying out the elements in a row as regions on a one-dimensional axis with their widths given by `weights`, and using `offset` as the point on the axis from which we pick the
region it's part of:

[image: An illustration of the elements ["a", "b", "c"] with weights [1, 3, 2] laid out on an axis]

We'd expect:

```rust
foo(elements, weights, 0.9) == Some("a")
foo(elements, weights, 1.2) == Some("b")
foo(elements, weights, 2.5) == Some("b")
foo(elements, weights, 4.0) == Some("c")
foo(elements, weights, 5.0) == Some("c")
```

Or indeed, that `foo(elements, weights, offset)` returns `"a"` for any `offset` in [0.0, 1.0), `"b"` for any `offset` in [1.0, 4.0), `"c"` for any offset in [4.0, 6.0), and `None` otherwise.

This feels like a very common and basic algorithm and so I feel like it probably has a canonical name, but I don't know one and have not been successful in searching for one online. Does this algorithm have a common name?

Comment: Maybe bucketing? Binning?

Comment: Maybe it has a name, but it is a specific case of *linear search*. You would normally preprocess the weights array and turn it into running sums, so that [1,3,2] would become [1,4,6], and then you can use the more efficient *binary search* algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean prefix sum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Comment: This would be "from a list of elements and weights, return the element where the prefix sum of the weights exceeds the `offset`".